# How to execute specific JavaScript to enable specific panel after postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I would like to find out is there a way to execute a specific javascript that will trigger the visibility of a specific block AFTER post back?

This is the link button that suppose to do the job

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtView" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-xs btn-default" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("OrderId.OrderId") %>' CommandName='<%# "Details" %>'><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></asp:LinkButton>     <%--Order Datails--%>
```

This is the script i want to execute after postback, to toggle the visibility of a specific block

```
Response.Write("$('').hide(); $('#orderDetails').show()");
```

Section of my current code

```
   <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" OnItemCommand="ListView1_ItemCommand">
                               <ItemTemplate>
                                   <tr>
                                       <td><asp:Label ID="lblOrderNo" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("OrderId.OrderId") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                                       <td><asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" Text='<%# String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", Eval("DateOfPayment") ) %>'></asp:Label></td>
                                       <td><asp:Label ID="lblAmount" runat="server" Text='<%# String.Format("{0:C}", Eval("FinalAmount")) %>'></asp:Label></td>
                                       <td class="text-center">
                                           <div class="btn-group">
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtView" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-xs btn-default" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("OrderId.OrderId") %>' CommandName='<%# "Details" %>'><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></asp:LinkButton>     <%--Order Datails--%>
                                          <%--  <asp:Button ID="lbtView" runat="server" Text="Button" CssClass="btn btn-xs btn-default" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("OrderId.OrderId") %>' CommandName='<%# "Details" %>' href="#"></asp:Button>--%>
                                           <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtInvoice" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-xs btn-default" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("OrderId.OrderId") %>' CommandName='<%# "Invoice" %>'><i class="fa fa-file-text"></i></asp:LinkButton>        <%--Order Invoice   --%>                                                
                                            </div>
                                       </td>
                                   </tr> 
                               </ItemTemplate>
                           </asp:ListView>
```

Section of the relevant class

```
protected void ListView1_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Details")
    {
        Response.Write("$('').hide(); $('#orderDetails').show()");
        OId = e.CommandArgument.ToString();


        //Bind order items
        lblOrderNo.Text = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
        Payment p = PaymentDB.getPaymentFromOD(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        List<OrderItem> oiList = OrderDetailsDB.getOrderItems(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        lblOrderDate.Text = p.DateOfPayment.ToShortDateString();
        lblTodtal.Text = p.FinalAmount.ToString("C");

        //---------------------------------Order Items Bind


        //----------------------------------------------------------------Status Update-----------
        BindStatus(oiList);

    }
    else if (e.CommandName == "Invoice")
    {
        Session["orderID"] = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
        Server.Transfer("order-invoice.aspx");
    }
}
```

Since by default #orderDetails is hidden, so whenever the page re-load it will turn hidden again, in other words i have to try only toggle the visibility of the block AFTER the page load. Or is anyone have other suggestion on how to do this?

Comment: you need to store the selected one in session at server side, and in page load you need to check for session and enable that tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a script tag with ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock if you want like so:

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "MyScript", "alert('hello');", true)
```

But I might recommend using a placeholder (or panel) to control visibility of any content in server side:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="orderDetailsPlaceholder" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <div id="orderDetails">
        Content
    </div>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

---

And in any event on code behind:

```
orderDetailsPlaceholder.Visible = true
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh yea, totally forgot about the use of placeholder, it indeed help curb the issue. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If `orderDetails` is a server control then just use `orderDetails.Visible = true` to display it. No need for Javascript.

If it's not a server control you'll need to ensure it's initially hidden client-side with CSS and your Javascript registration block should be `Response.Write("$('').hide(); $('#" + orderDetails.ClientID + "').show()");`

Note that really you should be registering your script with `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` and since you're using jQuery add your script to the `$(document).ready` event so it runs after DOM load.